# Javascript move characters in string?

Tags: javascript, string, character

I have a formula and I need to move characters in thousands of formulas. The quantity needs to be moved to the front of the equation, I'm close but cannot figure out how.
Example of formula:

```
const formula = '(({oval}) && ({2inchby3inch}) && {qty} >= 91000  && {qty} <=91999  && {whitebopp})';
var index1 = (formula.indexOf("{qty}")) - 5;
var index2 = (formula.indexOf("&& {whitebopp}")) - 15;
console.log(formula.slice(1)+formula.slice(index1, index2));
```

This code prints out `"({oval}) && ({2inchby3inch}) && {qty} >= 91000  && {qty} <=91999  && {whitebopp})) && {qty} >= 91000  && "` when I want it to print `"(({qty} >= 91000  && {qty} <=91999) && ({oval}) && ({2inchby3inch}) && {whitebopp}) "`
What am I doing wrong? Right now the desired text is being pasted at the end, I want it pasted one character after the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split() and reduce() to rearrange the array

```js
let formula = '(({oval}) && ({2inchby3inch}) && {qty} >= 91000  && {qty} <=91999  && {whitebopp})';
formula = formula.slice(1, -1)
let nformula = "(" + formula.split(" && ").reduce((b, a) => a.includes('{qty}') ? [a, ...b] : [...b, a], []).join(" && ") + ")"
console.log(nformula)
```